# Lateinische oder germanische Etymologie? Drückt „das gleiche Wort“ wirklich dasselbe aus?

Tags: etymology

Die Liste ist groß, vermute ich:

```
Germanisch          -      Nicht-germanisch
---------------     -      ----------------
Erdkunde            -      Geographie 
verallgemeinern     -      generalisieren
… (usw.)            -      … (etc.)
```

Dies sind Wörter, die wenigstens für einen bestimmten Kontext Synonyme sind. Für den Lerner ist es schwierig, einen Unterschied zu erkennen; nur den Ursprung erkennt man sofort. Die erste Spalte (die viel größer sein soll) ist germanisch; die zweite griechisch, lateinisch.

- *Wie wirkt auf die Ohren der Muttersprachler dieser Unterschied zwischen Etymologien? Oder ist es einfach entbehrlich, sich darum zu kümmern?*

---

**Der Sinn hinter dieser Frage**: Ich habe mal einen Deutschkurs besucht, bei dem rund ein Drittel der Studierenden eine römische Sprache als Muttersprache hatte (Französisch, Portugiesisch, Spanisch). Kein Wunder, dieses Drittel hat überwiegend die aus dem Latein abgeleiteten Wörter viel öfter als die in der ersten Spalte genutzt. Beim Sprechen hat uns oft die Lehrerin unterbrochen, um uns einzureden, eine germanische Variante zu nutzen. Heutzutage weiß ich nicht genau, worauf ihre Empfehlung basiert. Ob es wirklich für den Muttersprachler anders klingt oder ob sie das halt nur als Wortschatzaufbauübung gemacht hat, d. h., damit wir Synonyme lernen.

Comment: Ich verwende zum Beispiel niemals aktiv "Erdkunde" oder "generalisieren". Das erste Wort wird in Österreich einfach kaum verwendet und das zweite wird überhaupt kaum verwendet.

Comment: Das hängt sehr vom Wort ab und sehr von Deiner Umgebung. Wie Walter Tross schreibt sind viele Worte lt./gr. Ursprungs, ohne dass es der Sprecher weiß. Und in gebildeteren Kreisen werden auch auch erkennbare Fremdworte ohne zu zögern benutzt. Eine universale Empfehlung kann man deswegen m.E. nicht geben.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In aller Regel bedeuten die zwei Wörter tatsächlich dasselbe. Das germanische Wort ist normalerweise das gängigere Wort. Das könnte ein Grund sein, warum die Lehrerin darauf einen großen Wert gelegt hat.

Bei vielen Wörtern aus dem Lateinischen oder Griechischen darfst du auch nicht davon ausgehen, dass Muttersprachler diese verstehen. Solche Wörter stehen dann auch in sogenannten „Fremdwörterlexika“.
Studierte haben in aller Regel einen größeren Wortschatz. Werden in deinem Fachgebiet bestimmte Fremdwörter verwendet, so erweitert sich dein Wortschatz noch mehr. Das heißt aber nicht, dass man diese Wörter – insbesondere in der Umgangssprache – verwendet. Es sei denn, man bildet sich was drauf ein – das nenne ich dann aber [prätentiös](http://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/pr%C3%A4tenti%C3%B6s)(oder schlicht eingebildet, hochnäsig oder anmaßend).

Ein Beispiel: Das Wort [exorbitant](http://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/exorbitant) ist mir geläufig. Wird es von jemandem verwendet, brauche ich nicht nachzufragen, was es bedeutet. Dennoch verwende ich das Wort selbst nur mal alle Jubeljahre. Und es gibt schlichtweg viele Deutsche, die das Wort nicht verstehen. (Sie können es sich aus dem Kontext denken, aber das Wort könnten sie nicht definieren, wenn es ohne Kontext gegeben wird.)

Also: In der deutschen Sprache sind die germanischen Wörter gängiger, werden in der Fachsprache häufig von Fremdwörtern verdrängt. Nur eine Handvoll dieser Fremdwörter finden auch im Smalltalk ihre Anwendung.

---

Apart: Und wenn du jedes Wort in meiner Antwort genauer anschaust, fällt dir auf, dass nahezu alle germanisch sind.

---

Bezüglich der Kommentare von Walter Tross:
Es ist korrekt, dass im Grundwortschatz viele Wörter sind, welche nicht germanischen Ursprung haben. Und es ist auch richtig, dass wir (= 08/15-Anwender) gar nicht erkennen, welche Herkunft ein Wort hat.
Wie aber auch korrekterweise angemerkt, findet sich zu diesen Wörtern häufig auch gar kein Pendant (= Gegenstück) mehr im Sprachwortschatz. In Bezug auf diese Frage könnte man solche Wörter eigentlich getrost vernachlässigen.

Doch selbst wenn man diese miteinbezieht, so ist dennoch immer noch der Anteil germanischer Wörter signifikant (= erheblich, wesentlich) größer als der Anteil jener Wörter, die wir aus dem Lateinischen, Griechischen oder Französischem integriert (= übernommen) haben.

Also, ich möchte gar nicht der Aussage von Walter Tross widersprechen; dennoch denke ich, dass dies hier zu vernachlässigen ist, da es keinen Effekt (= Auswirkung) auf das Endergebnis hat.

Anmerkung: Ich habe jetzt in diesem Edit meines Erachtens gerade mal vier Wörter benutzt, die relevante (ok, jetzt fünf Wörter) Beispiele in Hinsicht auf die Frage sind. Zumindest sind dies Wörter, die meiner Meinung nach im erweiterten Sprachwortschatz zu finden sind, sprich nicht zum Grundwortschatz gehören, wo sich aber bereits ein häufiger verwendetes germanisches Wort im Grundwortschatz befindet.

Comment: Die letzte Aussage ist _diskutabel_ ;-). Schon im ersten Satz haben 3 Wörter lateinischen Ursprung: _Regel_, _germanisch_ und _normal_.

Comment: @WalterTross Was also etwa 5% sind. Passt :)

Comment: Autsch, nicht im ersten Satz sondern im ersten Paragraphen. Aber auch _passen_ kommt aus dem Lateinischen über dem Französischen... Was ich sagen will: viele Fremdwörter werden gar nicht mehr als solche empfunden, und bei vielen fehlt schon seit Jahrhunderten (oder gar Jahrtausenden) die germanische Alternative.

Comment: @WalterTross Passiert... (jaja, ich weiß, gleiche Herkunft wie passen). Dein Punkt ist mir schon klar. Es gibt natürlich auch eine enorme Anzahl..oh.. eine Vielzahl an Wörter, die wir tagtäglich verweden, die nicht aus dem germ... teutonischen kommen. Aber ich denke die Frage zielte schon auf eine bestimmte Gruppe von Wörter ab. Herkunft > Etymologie; bedeutend,wesentlich > signifikant; riesig > enorm (und ja, mir ist bewusst man kann auch sagen enorm > gewaltig – alles eine Frage der Betrachtung) ;)

Answer (score 2):

Erdkunde ist etymologisch eher Geo*logie*, im Gebrauch wird es aber mit Geographie gleichgesetzt.

Der größte Unterschied besteht darin, wie das Gesagte/Geschriebene vom Hörer/Leser wahrgenommen wird. „Generalisieren“ z. B. klingt etwas strenger als „verallgemeinern“, obwohl es dasselbe bedeutet. Im zweiten Fall ist es genau umgekehrt: Da klingt „Erdkunde“ ein bisschen veraltet.

Comment: Es gibt, also, keine allgemeingültige Regel, kein allgemeines Kriterion, um die Etymologie zu wählen. Es hängt vom Wort ab, wenn ich richtig verstehe. Das habe ich befurchtet.

Comment: Die Wahl hängt von deinem Publikum ab.